# WAMP PHP/Apache selectively refusing to parse php pages

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have many years experience of working with Apache/PHP/MySQL directly and have only just started using WAMP.

I installed WAMP last week and had my first 4 PHP/MySQL websites up and running immediately. How much easier is this I began to think! That is until I added a fifth site and cannot get php to parse any php file below the websites root directory.

I have a test.php file containing just the word **'hello'**, ho HTML tags and no PHP directives.
If I place this into **/wamp/www/ob/test.php** it works, if I place it into **/wamp/www/ob/html/test.php** the browser comes up with *'You have chosen to open test.php, what should Firefox do with this file?* Basically php failed to parse it.

My other sites are working fine with identical setup and this site plus three others were downloaded using Filezilla.
Can anybody help please before I uninstall WAMP and go back to installing Apache/MySQL/PHP manually.

Comment: doesn't WAMP imply that you are on a windows environment while your paths don't look very windows-like?

Comment: I have this problem occasionally on a production site after making a change to the file and saving it.  Usually, it's solved after a few page reloads.  Once it's solved, I don't get it any more.  Our site is LAPP (postgres instead of mysql).

Comment: So you have a txt file, with no headers, no PHP code, and you're surprised FF does not know what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Either the php handler is not turned on for that directory, or the content-type of the returned data is set wrong.

My WampDeveloper Pro setup has this...

```
<Directory "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/*/webroot">
    AddType text/html .php .php4 .php5 .phps
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php5
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</Directory>
```

This turns on PHP for all website folders.

Has a `DefaultType text/html` in httpd.conf for fallback.

Also check any .htaccess files, they might be setting content-type to something other than 'text/html'.

Answer (score 0):

The pages on the Internet that explain how to make Apache parse the PHP that you add to a file with the extension HTML suggest this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm
```

If your Apache server is configured for php5 but not php, then the result, I believe, is the refusal described.  I changed what I added to .htaccess to this (notice the digit 5):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm
```

That fixed the problem for me.